# Capacity of vectors created with macro

Tags: rust

```rust
let vec_macro = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
let mut vec = Vec::new();

for i in 0..5 {
    vec.push(i)
}

println!("Capacity of vec with macro: {}", vec_macro.capacity());
println!("Capacity of vec push: {}", vec.capacity());

// Result: 
// Capacity of vec with macro: 5
// Capacity of vec push: 8
```

I created 2 vectors, first one with macro `vec!` and the second one with `Vec::new()`, then I push item from 0 to 4 into them. The expected result is the capacity of these two vectors are the same, but it's not. Is this the bug in the implementation of `vec!`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The macro knows the number of elements, so it creates the vector with the optimal capacity (see also [`with_capacity()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity)).

Your loop invokes `push()` several times, but this operation does not know by itself when we will stop pushing elements.
So the strategy behind this is to amortize the cost of dynamic memory reallocation with an exponential capacity (0, 4, 8, 16, 32... for example on my computer).
When you push very few elements, the capacity stays low (we do not waste too much unused allocated memory), but if you push many elements, the reallocations will grow by bigger and bigger steps in order to happen not too often.

At the moment, we see that it simply doubles the capacity (whatever it is) when it is exhausted.
If we start from zero then just push, it seems to choose 4 as initial capacity then doubles it as needed, but if we start with 5 it will still continue to double the capacity (10, 20...).
However, what we see now is not guaranteed and might change at any time in future releases.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that create vec with macro we already known the number of elements so it will just use `with_capacity`.

But then I continue to push a new item in `vec_macro`, then the capacity of `vec_macro` will be 5x2 = 10 (rather than just 8 like I push in vec::new). So, is `10` a weird number (not a power of 2)

Comment: @LeVuMinhHuy The detail of this strategy may change at any time. I guess at the moment it simply doubles the capacity (whatever it is) when it is exhausted. If we start from zero then just push, it seems to choose 4 as initial capacity then doubles it as needed (and yes these are powers of 2), but if we start with 5 it will still continue to double capacity (10, 20...). But remember that what we see know might change at any time in future releases.

Answer (score 2):

`vec![a, b, ...]` is not the same as a repeated push. If you look at the source code for the macro, it looks like this:

```
    ($($x:expr),+ $(,)?) => (
        $crate::__rust_force_expr!(<[_]>::into_vec(box [$($x),+]))
    );
```

The important part is the `<[_]>::into_vec(box [$($x),+])`:

- `box [$($x),+]` is special syntax to create a "boxed slice" directly on the heap, as opposed to creating it on the stack and then moving it to the heap
- `<[_]>::into_vec` calls [`slice::into_vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.into_vec)

If we look at the source code of `into_vec`:

```rust
    pub fn into_vec<T, A: Allocator>(b: Box<[T], A>) -> Vec<T, A> {
        unsafe {
            let len = b.len();
            let (b, alloc) = Box::into_raw_with_allocator(b);
            Vec::from_raw_parts_in(b as *mut T, len, len, alloc)
        }
    }
```

And the signature of `Vec::from_raw_parts_in`:

```rust
pub unsafe fn from_raw_parts_in(
    ptr: *mut T,
    length: usize,
    capacity: usize,
    alloc: A
) -> Self;
```

You can see that the slice length is passed as both the `Vec` length and capacity.

The `Vec` documentation specifies this behavior of the macro:

> `vec![x; n]`, `vec![a, b, c, d]`, and
> [`Vec::with_capacity(n)`][`Vec::with_capacity`], will all produce a `Vec`
> with exactly the requested capacity. If `[len] == [capacity]`,
> (as is the case for the [`vec!`] macro), then a `Vec<T>` can be converted to
> and from a [`Box<[T]>`][owned slice] without reallocating or moving the elements.

As prog-fh said, `Vec::push` will exponentially reallocate when necessary, and will not end on a capacity of `5` unless you otherwise set the capacity manually via `with_capacity` or otherwise. It should be noted that this exponential growth is an implementation detail, not guaranteed by the `Vec` documentation.